# EXT JS 3.0 Grid , Show column when data is not empty

Tags: extjs

Is there a way to show columns only when they have data in them?

```
var grid = new Ext.grid.GridPanel({
    width:938,
    height:auto,
    store: store,
    renderTo: 'Div',

    // grid columns
    columns:[
        {coloum1},
        {coloum2},
        {coloum3},
        {coloum4} ] }};
```

// Only show column when it has data

Comment: you mean when a particular column doesn't have data in it then the column should not be visible right?

Answer (score 0):

In the store config use the `load` event.

```
var myStore = new JsonStore({

.. config..
listener :
{
   'load': function(){

        /*
          Code to check if the column data is empty - returns true/false
        */
        if(isEmpty)
        {
          mygrid.getColumnModel().setHidden(colIndex,true);
        }

}

});
```

Relevant API doc [here](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/3-4/#!/api/Ext.grid.ColumnModel-method-setHidden)

This is blind coding and written without testing. But it should work.

Comment: How do I loop through the records in the store to find whether a particular coloum is not empty.

Comment: Decode `json` and turn the `json` into a object. Use the method [hasOwnProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/HasOwnProperty) to check if the object has a property with the same name as used in json to column mapping of the grid.